# Why characters are 'undefined' in internet explorer but not in other browsers

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest

Please take a look at the site [tdsoft.se](http://tdsoft.se)
The script on that page works in opera, firefox chrome etc and prints out "random_1" as it is suposed to do, but in internet explorer it just prints out ("**undefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefined**"), that is 'undefined' for each letter. My question is if some of you bright fellows out there might know the answer to this problem?

EDIT_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*____**

Here's the code

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var txt;
var buildName = "";
var xmlhttp;
/**
 * Find a longest common subsenquence.
 *
 * Note: this is not necessarily the only possible longest common subsequence though!
 */
function lcs(listX, listY) {
        return lcsBackTrack(
                lcsLengths(listX, listY),
                listX, listY, 
                listX.length, listY.length);
}

/**
 * Iteratively memoize a matrix of longest common subsequence lengths.
 */
function lcsLengths(listX, listY) {
        var lenX = listX.length;
        var lenY = listY.length;

        // Initialize a lenX+1 x lenY+1 matrix
        var memo = [lenX+1];
        for (var i = 0; i < lenX+1; i++) {
                memo[i] = [lenY+1];
                for (var j = 0; j < lenY+1; j++) {
                        memo[i][j] = 0;
                }
        }

        // Memoize the lcs length at each position in the matrix
        for (var i = 1; i < lenX+1; i++) {
                for (var j = 1; j < lenY+1; j++) {
                        if (listX[i-1] == listY[j-1]) {
                                memo[i][j] = memo[i-1][j-1] + 1;
                        }
                        else {
                                memo[i][j] = Math.max(
                                        memo[i][j-1],
                                        memo[i-1][j]);
                        }
                }
        }

        return memo;
}

/**
 * Recursively read back a memoized matrix of longest common subsequence lengths
 * to find a longest common subsequence.
 */
function lcsBackTrack(memo, listX, listY, posX, posY) {

        // base case
        if (posX == 0 || posY == 0) {
                return "";
        }

        // matcth => go up and left
        else if (listX [posX-1] == listY[posY-1]) {
                return lcsBackTrack(memo, listX, listY, posX-1, posY-1) + listX[posX-1];
        }

        else {
                // go up
                if (memo[posX][posY-1] > memo[posX-1][posY]) { 
                        return lcsBackTrack(memo, listX, listY, posX, posY-1);
                }

                // go left
                else {
                        return lcsBackTrack(memo, listX, listY, posX-1, posY);
                }
        }
}

function loadXMLDoc(url,cfunc)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=cfunc;
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}


function myFunction()
{

    loadXMLDoc("http://tdsoft.se/testni.html",handleXML);


}
var checkState = function(xmlhttp, callback) {

try{
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        callback();
        } 
        else {
            // Check back again 1 sec later
            setTimeout(checkState, 1000);
        }
    }
    catch(err){
        setTimeout(checkState, 1000);
    }
};


function handleXML()
  {
checkState(xmlhttp, function() {

   txt=xmlhttp.responseText;
buildName = "random_1";
var myvar = "";
txt = "" + txt;
var lcsString = lcs(txt, buildName);
document.write(lcsString);
});
  }
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="myFunction()">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which version(s) of internet explorer have you tried?

Comment: Sounds like it's a character encoding issue. Make sure that your page is displaying using the same encoding as the response text.

Comment: What is the code, your document.write or whatever you are doing shows nothing on view source.

Comment: @epascarello that only seems to happen in IE other browsers show the JS script block

Comment: `var memo = [lenX+1];` This doesn't create a lenX+1 array, it creates a single-element array with value (lenX+1) as that element. Since you're then initialising all the elements yourself you just need `[]` really.

Comment: Works for me in IE8 under a debugger. Can you try dumping out the value of txt? Since I'd guess that's the culprit, since that's the only place you seem to source returned character values from. Also any reason why you're including jQuery but not using $.ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not working in IE, `listX [posX-1]`. The result of this is "undefined" so you sould use another way to get the char like `chatAt()` method

Comment: @Sotiris So how would that look when implemented? listX.charAt([posX-1]) Don't work

Comment: something like listX.charAt(posX-1), try It.

Comment: It just says "/html>" now, but is still working in the other browsers

Comment: it should be that the html code is bad. this is other problem now.

Answer (score 1):

`[lenY + 1]`, for one, does not initialize an array with `lenY + 1` elements. It initializes an array with one element set to `lenY + 1`. Not that that matters, because you set them anyways, to zero... just change that to `[]` both times.

I'm having trouble figuring out your code, but I believe the problem is that IE only allows you to access string characters using `charAt`, and not using the bracket notation, which you appear to be using here:

```
listX[i-1] == listY[j-1]
```

and here:

```
else if (listX [posX-1] == listY[posY-1]) {
```

So those comparisons would always return `true`. Could that be the issue?

Answer (score -1):

Was surprised IE has special meta to specify IE mode.
Setting it to IE8 solves the issue ! Characters are becoming accessible by [] operator.

See:
[IE modes](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=access%20to%20character%20in%20ie8%20javascript%20undefined&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CDAQFjAB&url=http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/02/02/how-internet-explorer-8-document-mode-affects-javascript/&ei=TU4gT96IJ4yf-wbQt4XEBA&usg=AFQjCNHO8q-fDqLwUjHhvG4msGwgbCcz0A)